# Heroku push fails to compile. Error points to node-sass. Possible dependency mismatch, log included

Tags: git, heroku, ionic-framework, node-sass

Sorry if this has been asked/answered before. Similar questions I found over google either had open tickets, or people suggested downgrading dependencies. I am unclear as to why the build is failing, when it seems to be working properly on my local machine.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

```
Counting objects: 28, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (26/26), done.
Writing objects: 100% (28/28), 2.72 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 28 (delta 19), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  4.1.1
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   2.14.4
remote:
remote:        Downloading and installing node 4.1.1...
remote:        npm 2.14.4 already installed with node
remote:
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Skipping cache (new runtime signature)
remote:
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Pruning any extraneous modules
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote:
remote:        > node-sass@0.9.6 install /tmp/build_506a4990caa900fce789184be89dc03b/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
remote:        > node build.js
remote:
remote:        (node) child_process: options.customFds option is deprecated. Use options.stdio instead.
remote:        make: Entering directory `/tmp/build_506a4990caa900fce789184be89dc03b/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/build'
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/binding/binding.o
remote:        In file included from ../binding.cpp:1:0:
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Signature> NanNew(v8::Handle<v8::FunctionTemplate>, int, v8::Handle<v8::FunctionTemplate>*)’:
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:189:78: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Signature::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Handle<v8::FunctionTemplate>&, int&, v8::Handle<v8::FunctionTemplate>*&)’
remote:             return v8::Signature::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), receiver, argc, argv);
remote:                                                                                      ^
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:189:78: note: candidate is:
remote:        In file included from /app/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/node.h:42:0,
remote:                         from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:23,
remote:                         from ../binding.cpp:1:
remote:        /app/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:4675:27: note: static v8::Local<v8::Signature> v8::Signature::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate>)
remote:           static Local<Signature> New(
remote:                                   ^
remote:        /app/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:4675:27: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 4 provided
remote:        In file included from ../binding.cpp:1:0:
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h: At global scope:
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:271:3: error: redefinition of ‘v8::Local<T> NanNew(P) [with T = v8::StringObject; P = v8::Local<v8::String>]’
remote:           NanNew<v8::StringObject, v8::Handle<v8::String> >(
remote:           ^
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:264:3: error: ‘v8::Local<T> NanNew(P) [with T = v8::StringObject; P = v8::Local<v8::String>]’ previously declared here
remote:           NanNew<v8::StringObject, v8::Local<v8::String> >(
remote:           ^
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:289:36: error: redefinition of ‘template<class T> v8::Local<v8::RegExp> NanNew(v8::Local<v8::String>, v8::RegExp::Flags)’
remote:           NAN_INLINE v8::Local<v8::RegExp> NanNew(
remote:                                            ^
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:283:36: error: ‘template<class T> v8::Local<v8::RegExp> NanNew(v8::Handle<v8::String>, v8::RegExp::Flags)’ previously declared here
remote:           NAN_INLINE v8::Local<v8::RegExp> NanNew(
remote:                                            ^
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:301:36: error: redefinition of ‘template<class T, class P> v8::Local<v8::RegExp> NanNew(v8::Local<v8::String>, v8::RegExp::Flags)’
remote:           NAN_INLINE v8::Local<v8::RegExp> NanNew(
remote:                                            ^
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:295:36: error: ‘template<class T, class P> v8::Local<v8::RegExp> NanNew(v8::Handle<v8::String>, v8::RegExp::Flags)’ previously declared here
remote:           NAN_INLINE v8::Local<v8::RegExp> NanNew(
remote:                                            ^
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:481:19: error: ‘NanNew’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
remote:               v8::String::ExternalAsciiStringResource *resource) {
remote:                           ^
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:481:19: warning: ‘always_inline’ attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:481:19: error: ‘v8::Local<v8::String> NanNew’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:475:36: error: previous declaration of ‘v8::Local<v8::String> NanNew(v8::String::ExternalStringResource*)’
remote:           NAN_INLINE v8::Local<v8::String> NanNew(
remote:                                            ^
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:481:7: error: ‘ExternalAsciiStringResource’ is not a member of ‘v8::String’
remote:               v8::String::ExternalAsciiStringResource *resource) {
remote:               ^
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:481:48: error: ‘resource’ was not declared in this scope
remote:               v8::String::ExternalAsciiStringResource *resource) {
remote:                                                        ^
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:495:27: error: redefinition of ‘template<class T> v8::Local<T> _NanEscapeScopeHelper(v8::Local<T>)’
remote:           NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEscapeScopeHelper(v8::Local<T> val) {
remote:                                   ^
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:490:27: error: ‘template<class T> v8::Local<T> _NanEscapeScopeHelper(v8::Handle<T>)’ previously declared here
remote:           NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEscapeScopeHelper(v8::Handle<T> val) {
remote:                                   ^
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:755:13: error: ‘node::smalloc’ has not been declared
remote:             , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
remote:                     ^
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:755:35: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘callback’
remote:             , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
remote:                                           ^
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(char*, size_t, int)’:
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:759:50: error: ‘callback’ was not declared in this scope
remote:                 v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, length, callback, hint);
remote:                                                          ^
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:759:60: error: ‘hint’ was not declared in this scope
remote:                 v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, length, callback, hint);
remote:                                                                    ^
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(const char*, uint32_t)’:
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:766:67: error: call of overloaded ‘New(v8::Isolate*, const char*&, uint32_t&)’ is ambiguous
remote:             return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
remote:                                                                           ^
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:766:67: note: candidates are:
remote:        In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:24:0,
remote:                         from ../binding.cpp:1:
remote:        /app/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::String>, node::encoding) <near match>
remote:         NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
remote:                                                ^
remote:        /app/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from ‘uint32_t {aka unsigned int}’ to ‘node::encoding’
remote:        /app/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate*, char*, size_t) <near match>
remote:         NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
remote:                                                ^
remote:        /app/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’
remote:        In file included from ../binding.cpp:1:0:
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(uint32_t)’:
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:770:61: error: could not convert ‘node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), ((size_t)size))’ from ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>’ to ‘v8::Local<v8::Object>’
remote:             return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), size);
remote:                                                                     ^
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanBufferUse(char*, uint32_t)’:
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:777:12: error: ‘Use’ is not a member of ‘node::Buffer’
remote:             return node::Buffer::Use(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
remote:                    ^
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘bool _NanGetExternalParts(v8::Handle<v8::Value>, const char**, size_t*)’:
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:2103:12: error: ‘class v8::String’ has no member named ‘IsExternalAscii’
remote:           if (str->IsExternalAscii()) {
remote:                    ^
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:2104:11: error: ‘ExternalAsciiStringResource’ in ‘class v8::String’ does not name a type
remote:             const v8::String::ExternalAsciiStringResource* ext;
remote:                   ^
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:2105:5: error: ‘ext’ was not declared in this scope
remote:             ext = str->GetExternalAsciiStringResource();
remote:             ^
remote:        ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:2105:16: error: ‘class v8::String’ has no member named ‘GetExternalAsciiStringResource’
remote:             ext = str->GetExternalAsciiStringResource();
remote:                        ^
remote:        ../binding.cpp: In function ‘void MakeCallback(uv_work_t*)’:
remote:        ../binding.cpp:138:35: warning: ‘void node::FatalException(const v8::TryCatch&)’ is deprecated (declared at /app/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/node.h:282): Use FatalException(isolate, ...) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
remote:             node::FatalException(try_catch);
remote:                                           ^
remote:        make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/binding.o] Error 1
remote:        make: Leaving directory `/tmp/build_506a4990caa900fce789184be89dc03b/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/build'
remote:        gyp ERR! build error
remote:        gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/tmp/build_506a4990caa900fce789184be89dc03b/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
remote:        gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-61-generic
remote:        gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_506a4990caa900fce789184be89dc03b/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_506a4990caa900fce789184be89dc03b/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
remote:        gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_506a4990caa900fce789184be89dc03b/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
remote:        gyp ERR! node -v v4.1.1
remote:        gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
remote:        gyp ERR! not ok
remote:        Build failed
remote:        npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-61-generic
remote:        npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_506a4990caa900fce789184be89dc03b/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_506a4990caa900fce789184be89dc03b/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "install" "--unsafe-perm" "--userconfig" "/tmp/build_506a4990caa900fce789184be89dc03b/.npmrc"
remote:        npm ERR! node v4.1.1
remote:        npm ERR! npm  v2.14.4
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! node-sass@0.9.6 install: `node build.js`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@0.9.6 install script 'node build.js'.
remote:        npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
remote:        npm ERR! not with npm itself.
remote:        npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
remote:        npm ERR!     node build.js
remote:        npm ERR! You can get their info via:
remote:        npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sass
remote:        npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/build_506a4990caa900fce789184be89dc03b/npm-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to [REPOSITORY].
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/[REPOSITORY].git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/[REPOSITORY].git'
```

Comment: WHich version of node do you have on your machine ? `v4.x.x` or `v0.12.x` ?

Comment: v4.x.x         herearesomerandomwordstomeetminimumcommentlength

Comment: Also getting this... but locally instead of on heroku

Comment: Same issue on Heroku

Comment: Same issue starting today.

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same problem. Downgrading the `node` version from `4.1.1` to `0.12.2` fixes the problem for me.

Comment: gah, it bothers me that downgrading tends to be the solution for a lot of similar issues like this. Turns out gulp sass was a legacy module that wasn't even being used in the application, so we nuked it from space. It didn't solve the problem, but it did "solve" it for us.

Comment: Perhaps the solution is not to make upgrades anymore -.-

Answer (score 3):

Without downgrading nodejs I came over it by specifying in my package.json the latest version of gulp sass. My old version of gulp-sass was 0.7.1 and now it is 2.0.4. Pushing to heroku works like a charm.